# While loop over range(0,5) with ran = ran[:-1]; ran != [] is always true

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a very simple code in Python and can't figure out why the loop won't stop. I specifically wanted to use a helper function inside the function. Any ideas?

```
def x():
    a = range(0,5)

    def y(ran):
        while ran != []:
            ran = ran[:-1]
            print(ran)
            return y(ran)

    return y(a)

x()
```

Comment: if my answer below was helpful, would you upvote it? I'm new here and it would help me a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `while ran:` as the condition you specified will always be true as `ran` is a range rather than a list.

Answer (score 0):

Python isn't generating the list from your range (saves time and memory), it's just using a [range object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range) to define what the range of numbers is.

When you execute `ran = ran[:-1]`, it returns a new range. The first time you run this, you start with `ran = range(0, 5)`, then `ran[:-1] == range(0, 4)`, then `range(0, 3)`, and so on. It never terminates because it eventually bottoms out at `range(0, 0)`, but that is *not* equal to `[]`.

You can fix this by changing your test to `while ran != range(0, 0):` (in Python 3.3+), or more simply `while ran:` because `range(0, 0)` evaluates to `False`.

Comment: @JamesLee, ...to mark your question solved, click the checkbox to the left of an answer.

Comment: @JamesLee No worries. That said, personally, I would have accepted *this* answer, being both first and more comprehensive, rather than the later one that just repeated content given both in the prior answer and the question's first comment.

Comment: @JamesLee yeah, you get used to the community, but typically the most complete answer or, if it's kind of a tie, the *first* most complete answer is a good one to mark as accepted. Gives future people with the same question the most helpful information with the least searching. If you can still change it, you might consider doing so. If not, upvotes are nice too!